# How to count text but excluding the words in brackets?

Tags: r, rstudio

I want to generate a new column shows counts of words for each film in the data frame, but some films' name including a bracket, and I don't want to count the words within the bracket, how can I code it? By the way, I am trying to use str.count function and I show my code that counts all words.

```
movie <- movie %>% mutate(words.of.title = str_count(str_trim(film), "\\S+"))
```

[image: Example dataframe]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option to check the count of words (alphanumeric characters) that are separated with either a space (`\\s`) or at the start of the string (`^`)

```
library(tidyverse)
movie %>% 
    mutate(words.of.title=str_count(str_trim(film), "(^|\\s)[[:alnum:]]+"))
```

Comment: Thank you, it is a simple code. but it doesn't work very well if there are more than one word in the bracket, such as "Blade Runner: The Final Cut (Secret Cinema 2018)", and the result is 7, but it should be 5. Can it be improved? Thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using gsub to remove the brackets and text within them. See below for a reprex and solution.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

df <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3),
                 film=c('Film','Film with (brackets)','Another film'))

movie <- df %>% 
  mutate(words.of.title = str_count(str_trim(gsub('\\(.*?\\)', '', film)), "\\S+"))

movie
#>   id                 film words.of.title
#> 1  1                 Film              1
#> 2  2 Film with (brackets)              2
#> 3  3         Another film              2
```

Created on 2019-01-02 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).